# How to keep a Spring Boot service running in a single thread and shared it across the application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, service, concurrency

This is a kinda complicated question I think: I have a backend Spring Boot Application with different endpoints. I want to have a unique Service that run indefinitely with some variables and different methods that modify those variables. I expect a concurrent access to that service, and also I need access to that service across the application.

I understand that Spring create an instance of the service each time a petition arrive, but I need to persist the value of the variables (in memory) inside the class across different petitions and I don't know how to do it.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class LimboQueueImpl implements LimboQueue {

  private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Long>();

  private int numberCounter = 0;

  @Override
  public String getCurrentUser() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean addPetition(Long userId) throws UserNotFoundException {
    int ticketNumber = this.addNumber();
    // TODO: save ticket
    return this.queue.add(userId);
  }

  @Override
  public Long getNextPetition() {
    return this.queue.isEmpty() ? null : this.queue.remove();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean deletePetition(Long userId) {
    return this.queue.remove(userId);
  }

  private synchronized int addNumber() {
    return this.numberCounter++;
  }

  private synchronized void resetNumberCounter() {
    this.numberCounter = 0;
  }
}
```

I appreciate any guidance or help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing seems like a default implementation of a Spring's @Bean. A default scope is singleton. Any time you inject this bean to any of the services (using Spring's DI), you'd get the same instance, hence the values will also be persisted in memory. Remember about the lifecycle of Spring Beans though, so if you need to persist those values when the context is killed (app is killed), you need to take care of it manually (or maybe Spring has some handy "on destroy" hook you can utilise to write it to file for example. But for the context of your question, simple Bean should suffice.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the guidance I will test it during the weekend and I will post the solution if it works.

Comment: I did exactly that in the past, there were no problems with this implementation. Remember about permanent persist if you need to cache it between app startups. But for a single run: beans live as long as an app context. So you should be good